# Need help on running a for loop to replace a line in a txt file and save it as new file in python

Tags: python, for-loop, replace, range

I want to edit a certain .txt file which in a line contains a string that I want to replace with a another string name and save them in a new .txt file. So far I have done the following code and the code only save the new editted .txt file for the last output which is 6 instead of all outputs from 1 until 6. The output .txt files from 1-5 has no text instead. Any ideas where the problem is and how I can fix my code so it works as intended? Thank you in advance.

```
input = open("C:\Users\...\file.txt", "rt")

for n in range(1,7):
    for line in input:
        output= open("file" + str(n) + "new.txt", "wt")
        output.write(line.replace("data_sample.csv", "data_"+ str(n) +"_new.csv"))
```

Comment: I think maybe because you are not closing the file.
Try adding output.close() after writing to it.
Or use a context manager which will automatically close the file after finishing working on it.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you only open your input file once. So once the `for line in input:` has executed, the input file is exhausted and the next `n` (2 in your case) has an exhausted file and so does nothing for 2 to 6. As has been said you should use a context manager (ie `with open(...) as ...`) to open and close the files.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Adham's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72041061/need-help-on-running-a-for-loop-to-replace-a-line-in-a-txt-file-and-save-it-as-n#comment127293630_72041061). I would also suggest moving reading the input file into the outermost for loop. The following snippet should create the files as expected

```
for n in range(1,7):
    input = open("C:\Users\...\file.txt", "rt")
    output= open("file" + str(n) + "new.txt", "wt")
    for line in input:
        output.write(line.replace("data_sample.csv", "data_"+ str(n) +"_new.csv"))
    output.close()
```

Comment: After putting output.close() I got the output files that I wanted. Thank you all for your help!